# Where do we get System.IdentityModel in .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: claims-based-identity, claims, .net-standard-2.0

I've got Claims and ClaimSet for my claims-based authentication.  I want to move my library from .NET Framework to .NET Standard 2.0 but I can't find an equivalent class.  There must be support for Claims-based authentication in .NET Standard 2.0, so I must be missing something obvious, right?  What is it?

Comment: it is not supported in .net standard: https://apisof.net/catalog/System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimSet

Answer (score 0):

install nuget package named System.ServiceModel.Primitives

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Security.Claims for Claims, ClaimSet hasn't been included unfortunately, but that shouldn't be to hard to overcome.

Relevant to create your own ClaimSet: [this article on docs.ms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.claims.claimset?view=netframework-4.8)

Also worth mentioning is [this github-repo (IdentityModel)](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel)